# view facebook page's pictures with facebook android SDK

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

Salam every body
I want to develop a project that allow to user to view latest picture uploaded in a certain pages
i'm new in facebook android sdk and i don't know what is the first step to do
can you give some directives to start this project?
best wishes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always recommend that developers who are looking to integrate Facebook into their apps to start with our documentation.  This [tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/android_hackbook/) on our developers page walks you through a sample app that gets you started with our most basic SDK functionalities such as logging in via Facebook, uploading a picture, and grabbing the user's profile picture for example.  Once you go through that, you should be well-versed enough to learn how to extend the SDK functionalities to do what you want.

This community is also very helpful when you have questions (but you have to provide context, sample code, and very thorough description of the problem you're facing).